# Is cryptography the same as Obfuscation?

Tags: cryptography, obfuscation

Obfuscation is the transformation of data, but as I understand it, obfuscation permanently transforms data while encryption just encrypts it and can be decrypted with a secret key later. So is cryptography a form for obfuscation or is it in a domain for it self? Im having trouble classifying them.

Thanks.

Comment: Just Wikipedia that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a terminology question answered simply by the wikipedia pages for each word.

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation does not transform data - it makes data difficult to interpret.

If I am writing malware and I want to make it difficult for analysts to understand the flow of logic, then instead of using a function called `print` I use a random string to name that function. "Print" has not been transformed into a random string, the function is just named that random string. There is nothing to 'revert' the random string to.

When you run a code obfuscator, it takes the names variables and functions, assigns them a key value (think: `variable1`, `function1`, etc.), then replaces those names with a random string (and sometimes the random string is itself obfuscated through a renaming function embedded in the code). This is not encryption or hashing. This is a complete renaming with random strings. Yes, you could also use encryption as a renaming function, but why take that computational hit? In the end, the variables and function names need to be consistent in the logic flow at runtime.

Comment: Im more thinking of obfusaction in the domain of releasing data sets etc. Lets say I generalize some value from "3.2"  to "<5". It is difficult to interpret but isnt it transformed?

Comment: Ok, then you will need to very, very clearly define what you mean by 'obfuscation' in your question. I'm not sure how anyone could equate 'encryption' with 'generalising values'.

Comment: Thats why I asked the question. Because I seem misunderstand the term obfuscation, and if it is the same in terms of data privacy vs obfuscating code, and if encryption is under the category of obfuscating. Obfuscation seems to be a very broad term then

Comment: @wandapong Obfuscation is a broad and generic term without a technical definition. Encryption is a specific term with a precise definition. In your data set example, the data is not being transformed, it is being summarised or aggregated.

Comment: According to a paper on data obfuscation that is a cetagory of obfuscation called Data Anonymization and is called generalization

Comment: That makes sense, but does that answer your question about the categorization of encryption in relationship with obfuscation? Generalization is not transformation, you report on the superset of information.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscation makes code difficult for a human (and potentially even a computer) to understand, but it is still usable as is.  Encryption makes code not usable as is, it must be decrypted to be useful.